# Composite Index and Covering Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-indexes, composite-index, covering-index

I have a table with (ID, col1, col2) & query of

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE col1 = 2
AND col2 = 7
```

Should I create a composite index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Composite ON table (ID, col1, col2)
```

or  covering index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Covering ON table ID INCLUDED (col1, col2)
```

Comment: FYI, if you have 2 questions, please post 2 question, unless the 2 are *very* closely related. These don't appear to be.

Comment: In regards to the index creation, the one that would help the data engine the most would be one on `col1` and `col2` with `ID` `INCLUDE`d; which neither of your indexes are. An index which is ordered on `ID` *first* is going to require a full scan for that query.

Comment: I would also recommend `(col1, col2) INCLUDE (ID)` although note that if `ID` is the clustering key it will be included anyway

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the indexes in your question will help the query you have. The reason for this is because the first sorting column is the `ID`, however, your filtering columns are on `col1` and `col2`; as such the index doesn't help the data engine quickly seek to the rows you need.

Let's put what you have into a classic phone book analogy. Let's say that the `ID` is the Phone Number, `Col1` the Surname, and `Col2` the Forename. If we use your index, the phone phone book is order by phone number, starting at the "lowest" phone number and ending at the "highest". If you want phone numbers for people called "John Smith" your only option is to go through the **entire** book and find every John Smith.

A traditional phone book, however, is ordered by the Surname, then Forename, and has the phone number for each beside them. This means that you can now easily service the question of "What are the phone numbers for John Smith"? Flick through the book to "Smith" first, then "John", and you have all the phone numbers.

So, what your index should look like is the following:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Composite ON table (col1, col2) INCLUDE (ID);
```

As noted by Charlieface as well, if your column `ID` is your clustered index then there is actually no need to `INCLUDE` it; the column(s) in the clustered index are automatically `INCLUDE`d in any `NONCLUSTERED` indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I understand for the way using covering index now. Can I know when can we use composite index instead of covering index?